# How to show a DIV (or another) based on a option selected in a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I have a dropdown menu which contains a list of all the states in the world.

For states outside EU I would like to show this message in a div "EXTRA EU Tax and duties NOT included. You will have to pay them upon delivery".

For EU member states, on the other hand, I would like to show "There are no import duties to pay".

I have created an array containing all the values ​​belonging to the member states of the European union. But I dont't understand how to set it up to make my idea work.

```js
var european = ["Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "United Kingdom"]
```

```html
<select size="1" autocomplete="shipping country" data-trekkie-id="shipping_country_field" data-backup="country" class="field__input field__input--select" aria-required="true" name="checkout[shipping_address][country]" id="checkout_shipping_address_country">
  <option data-code="DE" value="Germany">Deutschland</option>
  <option data-code="GB" value="United Kingdom">Vereinigtes Königreich</option>
  <option data-code="US" value="United States">Vereinigte Staaten</option>
  <option data-code="IT" selected="selected" value="Italy">Italien</option>
  <option data-code="EG" value="Egypt">Ägypten</option>
  <option data-code="GQ" value="Equatorial Guinea">Äquatorialguinea</option>
  <option data-code="ET" value="Ethiopia">Äthiopien</option>
  <option data-code="AF" value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option data-code="AX" value="Aland Islands">Ålandinseln</option>
  <option data-code="AL" value="Albania">Albanien</option>
  <option data-code="DZ" value="Algeria">Algerien</option>
  <option data-code="UM" value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">Amerikanische Überseeinseln</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Show/hide the div or label based on what's selected using a `change` event on the `<select>`. Or just type it inside each option already.

Comment: `document.getElementById("checkout_shipping_address_country").addEventListener("change",function() { let text = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; document.getElementbyId("msg").innerText = european.indexOf(text) === -1 ? "EXTRA EU Tax and duties NOT included. You will have to pay them upon delivery": "There are no import duties to pay" ; })`

Comment: I also suggest you have a "Please select" and test for no value

Answer (score 1):

```js
var european = ["Austria","Belgium","Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus","Czechia","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Ireland","Italy","Latvia","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Malta","Netherlands","Poland","Portugal","Romania","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","United Kingdom"]


function isEuropean(country){
  return european.indexOf(country)>=0;
}

//BIND SELECT Change
$(function(){
  $("#checkout_shipping_address_country").change(function() {
    onselection(this);
  });
})

function onselection(sel){
  console.log(sel.value);
  let country = sel.value;
  
  if(isEuropean(country)){
    $('#msg').text("EXTRA EU Tax and duties NOT included. You will have to pay them upon delivery");
  }else{
    $('#msg').text("There are no import duties to pay");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  size="1" autocomplete="shipping country" data-trekkie- data-backup="country" class="field__input field__input--select" aria-required="true" name="checkout[shipping_address][country]" id="checkout_shipping_address_country">
        <option data-code="DE" value="Germany">Deutschland</option>
        <option data-code="GB" value="United Kingdom">Vereinigtes Königreich</option>
        <option data-code="US" value="United States">Vereinigte Staaten</option>
        <option data-code="IT" selected="selected" value="Italy">Italien</option>
        <option data-code="EG" value="Egypt">Ägypten</option>
        <option data-code="GQ" value="Equatorial Guinea">Äquatorialguinea</option>
        <option data-code="ET" value="Ethiopia">Äthiopien</option>
        <option data-code="AF" value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option data-code="AX" value="Aland Islands">Ålandinseln</option>
        <option data-code="AL" value="Albania">Albanien</option>
        <option data-code="DZ" value="Algeria">Algerien</option>
        <option data-code="UM" value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">Amerikanische Überseeinseln</option>
        </select>
        
       <div id="msg"> </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the <select> to add the onchange because this select it's from shopify checkout and it is included with a snippet.

Comment: Bind the <select> Change by jQuery. Edited the answer snippet